# Deduce that f not is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Define $f : [0, 1) → C$ by $f(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$

Prove that $f$ is one-to-one, onto and continuous. Find a point in $[0, 1)$
and a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ in $[0, 1)$ such that $f(N)$ is not a neighborhood of $f(x)$ in C. Deduce that f is not a homeomorphism.

Attempt at a solution:

$2\pi x$ is the angle of the complex number $e^{2\pi ix}$. Since there are $2\pi$ radians in a full $360^{o}$ angle, if $x, y ∈ [0, 1)$ and
$e^{2\pi ix} = e^{2\pi iy}$, then $x = y$. Therefore f is one-to-one. Similarly, as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $2\pi x$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Therefore f is onto.

It remains to show that $f$ is continuous. And if we can show that the inverse of $f$ not is continuous we can deduce that f not is a homeomorphism.

edit: typo wrote $\mathbb{C}$ instead of C.

Comment: What does it mean for your inverse to be continuous? What point on the circle might be problematic?

Comment: @Brad A.M ...I understand that f([0, 1/2)) equals C intersected with the upper half plane minus the single point z = -1 and that this is not a neighborhood of z = 1 because any open ball around z = 1 must contain numbers in the lower half plane. But then i get a little confused about the definitions and about open and closed sets. Doesnt the above need  that [0, 1/2) is an open neighborhood of 0 in [0, 1) on the real line to have any significance? Is it? And if it is why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of $f$ is not continuous because a small neighborhood of $z=1$ is sent to the union of two disjoint intervals but a continuous function must send connected sets to connected sets.

Answer (score 0):

W̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶(̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶b̶i̶e̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶I̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶g̶o̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶)̶:̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶m̶a̶p̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶N̶O̶T̶ ̶o̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶(̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶:̶[̶0̶,̶1̶)̶→̶C̶f̶:̶[̶0̶,̶1̶)̶→̶C̶)̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶i̶s̶f̶(̶[̶0̶,̶1̶)̶)̶=̶{̶z̶∈̶C̶∣̶|̶z̶|̶=̶1̶}̶≠̶C̶f̶(̶[̶0̶,̶1̶)̶)̶=̶{̶z̶∈̶C̶∣̶|̶z̶|̶=̶1̶}̶≠̶C̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶r̶e̶f̶o̶r̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶p̶.̶ ̶B̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶e̶g̶s̶ ̶"̶i̶s̶ ̶f̶f̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶m̶b̶e̶d̶d̶i̶n̶g̶"̶?̶ ̶A̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶.̶

*Claim 1. $f$ is continuous*

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$, let $c \in [0, 1)$. Note that $|f(x)-f(c)| \leq 2$, for all $x \in [0, 1)$, so if $\epsilon>2$, we are done. Suppose $\epsilon \leq 2$. Let $\delta=arcsin(sup\{|f(c)-z| \mid z \in C \cap B_\mathbb{C}(f(c), \epsilon))\})$. I believe that $\delta$ does it, but it needs some verification and there's probably an easier way to go about this anyhow. (will outline how this works in a future edit) $\square$

*Claim 2. $f$ is not a homeomorphism.*

*Proof.* It suffices to show $f$ is not an open map. We find $[0, 1/2)$ is open in $[0, 1)$ but $f([0, 1/2))$ is not open in $C$. $\square$

I'll leave it to you to show *how* it is that $f([0, 1/2))$ is not open in $C$, but give you a few crucial hints. There are two main ways to prove this. The first proof is a trivial one using compactness. The other way is you suppose $f([0, 1/2))$ is open and get a nice little contradiction using the point $0$ and the basis of $C$ consisting of all open balls in $\mathbb{C}$ intersected with $C$.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Wait a sec...I misread your typo! Thought you meant you were substituting $C$ with $\mathbb{C}$ instead of the other way around. At some point in time, I WILL substitute $\mathbb{C}$ with $C$ myself, hence answering your question in a less awkward manner.

EDIT 2: Also, my continuity proof at the moment is STUPID! It needs correcting I don't start this semester in a week so I'm a bit rusty. Will tend to that in due time. Pretty sure my "not homeomorphism" proof is still fine, though.

EDIT 3: Ok, picked a $\delta$ that I think will do it. But it aint pretty!

EDIT 4: Fixed my misinterpretation of your typo!

Comment: You write [0,1/2) is open in [0,1). Can you also say that [0, 1/2) is an open neighborhood of 0 in [0, 1)? I am still at the very basics of this...

Comment: Ok, understandable. Yes you can say that. A neighborhood $x$ is a subset of the set $X$ a topological space operates on (some texts require that a neighborhood is open, some don't, Munkres requires open) which contains the element $x$.

Comment: whats confuses me is that i am thinking that any open neighborhood of 0 will contain negative values which gives a contradiction because the interval is closed on the left [0, *) and therefor  [0, 1/2) can not be an open neighborhood of 0 in [0, 1)

Comment: Ahhh...but here's the thing. I am working with the subspace topology ON $[0, 1)$ of the Euclidian topology on $\mathbb{R}$. $[0, 1/2)=(-1000, 1/2) \cap [0, 1)$, therefore it fits the criteria of what's open in the SUBSPACE topology. If you haven't herd of a subspace topology (I would assume you have if you're doing homeomorphisms), I could gladly explain what it is.

Comment: And regarding the continuity im thinking that
if you take an open ball B in the complex plane.
Then the intersection of B with C is either
the whole circle or an open part of it
and therefor $f^{-1}(B)$ is either the whole interval
or an open subinterval and in both 
cases that is an open subset of [0,1) which 
imply that f is continous.

Comment: I think you mean $C$ in "intersection of $B$ with $\mathbb{C}$".

Comment: yepp, i changed it...tired...typo after typo :)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about subspace topology. I read about it for the first time earlier today. I will reread that part.

Comment: In any case, your intuition is definitely correct. The question is proving it what you just said. I personally used epsilon-delta since that's generally the fastest way in the complex plane (or more generally a metric space) but either I have not found a very neat $\delta$ or that method is nasty. It's also possible that there might be an easier way to do it by inverse mapping trickery